# Using nodejs http to send progress indications

Tags: node.js, progress

I'm trying to send progress indications (to the client) of an http call I'm making to a third party api but I'm getting the error:

> Object `#<IncomingMessage>` has no method 'write'

It references `response.write(chunk.length)`

```
http.get('/other/api', function(response) {
    var body = '';

    response.on('data', function(chunk) {
        body += chunk;
        response.write(chunk.length);
    });
    response.on('end', function() {
        return fn(JSON.parse(body));
    });
});
```

**NOTE:** This is a snippet of code - `fn` is an argument passed into the function this snippet is used in.

I'm not quite sure I'm implementing this properly. Please advise.

Comment: You can't write anything in a `GET` request, that's what `POST` is for.

Comment: that doesn't make sense. The response has nothing to do with the http verb. You have to write the response.

Comment: @bflemi3 the `response` is not the response that you can write, that is the client side receiving the response from a get request, and not the server side processing a get request

Comment: ahhh, I see. If I were to send in a callback for notifications then I would have access to the response. I think that might work?